# Passing pointer to function causes segmentation fault when trying to retrieve value

Tags: c, pointers, openssl, segmentation-fault, memory-address

I am getting a segmentation fault with the following code. I am pretty sure it is because a function is trying to use the address of a variable instead of it's value. I am a bit new to pointers.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    EVP_PKEY        priv_key_p;
    X509_REQ        req_p;
    X509            cert;
    PKCS7           pkcs7;

        /*Need to store value in req_p and priv_key_p*/
    makecsr(&req_p, &priv_key_p, passphrase);

        /*Need to use value of req_p and priv_key_p*/
    create_cert(&req_p, &cert, &priv_key_p, passphrase);
}


int create_cert(X509_REQ *req_p, X509 *cert, EVP_PKEY *priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
{
    int i;
    long serial = 1;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    const EVP_MD *digest;
    X509_NAME *name;
    X509V3_CTX ctx;

    /* verify signature on the request */
    if (!(pkey = X509_REQ_get_pubkey (req_p))) <--- Segmentation fault here!
        int_error ("Error getting public key from request");
    ....
}
```

Using GDB, after makecsr has executed, I can print the value of priv_key_p and req_p no problem.

However, inside the create_cert function, I can only print the value by writing p *priv_key_p / *req_p

**Error**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7ebb747 in X509_REQ_get_pubkey ()
   from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code, i mean what are the types of your variable. In the present state it is difficult to answer this question.

Comment: `X509_REQ_get_pubkey (&req_p)` try this.(A shot in the dark)

Comment: The types are from the [OpenSSL library](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html), no luck with &req_p either

Comment: Could you provide the code from your function creating the CSR : makecsr ? I guess the error might come from here

Comment: @CamilleG. you were definitely on the right track, req_p was not being created properly due to incorrect pointer types / handling.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296250/assigning-a-pointer-returned-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I was passing in a wrong pointer type for req_p into create_cert.

Solution was to change create_cert to this:

`int create_cert(X509 *req_p, X509 **cert, EVP_PKEY **priv_key_p, char * passphrase)`

Comment: No it wasn't. Your create_cert should stay the same, the intern function from your makecsr has only to be modified. (as it does in the link provided in the previous comment !)

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
if (!(pkey = X509_REQ_get_pubkey (req_p))) <--- Segementation fault here!
    int_error ("Error getting public key from request");
    ....
```

try this one:

```
if (!(pkey == X509_REQ_get_pubkey (req_p))) <--- Segementation fault here!
    int_error ("Error getting public key from request");
    ....
```

Comment: You should point out that the first assigns to pkey, whereas the second compares to pkey. Hard to see the difference without them side by side.

Comment: The error lies within `X509_REQ_get_pubkey (req_p)` unfortunately