# Assigning a pointer returned from a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-value

I have a program which looks like this:

```
EVP_PKEY *generate_RSA_key_and_uuid(unsigned char uuid[16])
{
    EVP_PKEY        *key_p;
    key_p = EVP_PKEY_new();
    return key_p;  
}

int build_and_save_csr(int dn_entries, X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY *priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
{   
    priv_key_p = generate_RSA_key_and_uuid(uuid);
}

int makecsr(X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY *priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
{

    if (build_and_save_csr(2, req_p, priv_key_p, passphrase) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create csr file / private key...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    EVP_PKEY        *priv_key_p;
    X509_REQ        *req_p;

    makecsr(req_p, priv_key_p, passphrase);
    return 0;
}
```

After this has run, `*priv_key_p` should contain the value returned from `*generate_RSA_key_and_uuid`.

In gdb, I can see that at the end of `generate_RSA_and_uuid` that `key_p` contains the correct value but after `priv_key_p = generate_RSA_key_and_uuid(uuid);` has executed, `priv_key_p` is empty.

Does anybody know how to properly assign the value to the pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an extra level of indirection, otherwise you're just modifying local copies of the pointers and nothing gets returned:

```
int build_and_save_csr(int dn_entries, X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY **priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
{   
    *priv_key_p = generate_RSA_key_and_uuid(uuid);
}

int makecsr(X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY **priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
{
    if (build_and_save_csr(2, req_p, priv_key_p, passphrase) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create csr file / private key...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EVP_PKEY        *priv_key_p;
    X509_REQ        *req_p;

    makecsr(req_p, &priv_key_p, passphrase);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can use the function result (as you do already in `generate_RSA_key_and_uuid()`) to return the pointer (perhaps return NULL on error) - this gets rid of the need for the extra level of indirection.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `EVP_PKEY **priv_key_p` in the signature  of `build_and_save_csr`?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much, that was driving me nuts

Answer (score 4):

That's because you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
int makecsr(X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY *priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
```

Should be:

```
int makecsr(X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY **priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
```

You'll call it by:

```
makecsr(req_p, &priv_key_p, passphrase);
```

And you must also change:

```
int build_and_save_csr(int dn_entries, X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY *priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
```

to:

```
int build_and_save_csr(int dn_entries, X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY **priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
```

And do:

```
*priv_key_p = generate_RSA_key_and_uuid(uuid);
```

**That was for the fix, now the explanation:**

In this function:

```
int build_and_save_csr(int dn_entries, X509_REQ *req_p, EVP_PKEY *priv_key_p, char *passphrase)
{   
    priv_key_p = generate_RSA_key_and_uuid(uuid);
}
```

`prev_key_p` initially points to, well, somewhere. And then you say that it should now points to the value returned by `generate_RSA_key_and_uuid`.

The problem is that the new value of `priv_key_p` is only local to the function `build_and_save_csr`. Even if it's the same name, it's not the same variable.

This is fixed by adding another level of indirection.

It's actually the same problem as this:

```
void inc(int a) {
  a += 1;
}
```

That has no effect whereas the correct function would be:

```
void inc(int *a) {
  *a += 1;
}
```

In your case, your type is not `int` but `EVP_PKEY *`.